# How to Enable OTG Compability On my Samsung SM-T231

Tags: root-access, usb-on-the-go

Yesterday I bought one OTG Cable just for my tablet but for some reason it isn't compatible or it doesn't Read my OTG cable..Any solutions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your device

If it doesn't support then you have to deal with it